# Javascript .style in document.createElement not working

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.id = "control_random";
        link.href = document.location.href + "#";
        //link.style = "margin-left:200px";
```

The code marked with the `//` doesn't work.
And when I edit it using inspect element I notice that it hasn't been applied.

Comment: How did you know that it is not working??

Answer (score 3):

You must use `style.cssText`

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.id = "control_random";
link.style.cssText = "margin-left:200px; margin-right:100px;";
```

Other Ways...

```
link.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:200px; margin-right:100px;");
```

(Thanks to @ T.J. Crowder)

```
link.style.marginLeft = "200px";
link.style.marginRight = "100px";
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.
Didn't think it would be that simple. I just assumed you had to write it as it is displayed if it were html: style="margin-left:200px"

Comment: @Density: Or better yet: `link.style.marginLeft = "200px";` [More here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Comment: not necessarily, though while assigning a string is definitly wrong, you can access and set individual properties - [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp)

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know both as I'll be using this for other things too!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
link.style.margin = "200px";
```

also

```
link.style.marginLeft ="200px"
```

or simply use `.cssText = "your css"`

check this 
Click [here to view demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGZqoY)!
    Updated link
updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/weo9z2r5/8/)!